# Which are faster squares or roots?

Tags: optimization, loops, primes

```
for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)

for (int i = 2; i <= SQRT(n); i++)
```

just wondering which is faster I looked at some primitive algorithms for getting roots and it would seem to me that squaring the number would be faster but I don't know for sure. These loops are for determining a numbers "primeness".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't the comaprison be between

```
int sqrt = SQRT(n);
for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt; i++)
```

and

```
for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
```

The answer will depend on how many loop iterations you do. The sqrt method does less work per iteration, but it has a higher start-up cost. Mind you, this reeks of premature optimisation.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler may 'cache' result of SQRT (n), but i * i it should compute on each step.

Comment: The cache lookup would still not be faster than the multiplication.

Comment: Never mind the compiler. He should compute that square root explicitly OUTSIDE the loop and just compare to that value.

Answer (score 1):

Square root will take longer, unless it's implemented in hardware, lookup, or a special machine code version.  Newton iteration is the algorithm of choice; it converges quadratically.

Best to benchmark for yourself.  I'd recommend moving the call to square root outside the loop so you only do it once rather than every time you check the exit condition.

Comment: I really doubt you'll ever see a hardware implementation of square root that's even remotely close to the speed of a multiplication.

Comment: I wasn't sure if a lookup could compare.

Answer (score 1):

Why not skip both of them and use some clever maths? The Following code avoid both of them using the Property that Sum of the First `n` odd numbers is always a perfect square.

A shameless plug for my old [blogpost](http://lostincompilation.blogspot.com/2010/10/how-to-check-if-number-is-prime-trail.html)  (from my dead blog)

```
int isPrime(int n)
{
    int squares = 1;
    int odd = 3;

    if( ((n & 1) == 0) || (n < 9)) return (n == 2) || ((n > 1) && (n & 1));
    else
    {
        for( ;squares <= n; odd += 2)
        {
            if( n % odd == 0) 
                return 0;
            squares+=odd;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: When I have 15 rep i'll come back and one up this one for the "clever math" so until then iou +1

Answer (score 0):

The square will be faster.

But the square will overflow if n is larger than the square root of the largest int, and then the comparison will go wrong. The square root function could (and you would expect to) be implemented in such a way that is can be calculated on arguments all the way up to the largest representable int. That means it won't go wrong in that way.

In Java, the largest int is 2^31 - 1, which means its square root is just under 46341. If you want to look for primes larger than that, the squaring would stop you.